# Explanation for memory map timing in python when using multiple process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cpu-architecture, timing, memory-mapping

I am using a 36 core HPC node. The specification is that the node has 2 Intel Xeon E5-2695 v4 CPUs with 18 cores each. I am trying to write to a memory map from the main process and the sub process reads the memory map and updates it. The sub process sleeps for some time before updating. I launch multiple sub process in parallel.

I was doing some performance testing and I encountered a scenario that I have explained below my code results.

```py
import time
from mmap import mmap
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

f = open("results.csv", "w")
f.write("mmap_time,total_time\n")

def sub_process(m, mutex):
        while True:
                mutex.acquire()
                if m[0] == 72:                                  # equivalent to H
                        time.sleep(0.001)                       # sleep for 1 millisecond
                        m.seek(0)
                        m.write(bytes("child", "utf-8"))
                mutex.release()
                time.sleep(0.00001)

n = 80                                                          #Num of Subprocess

m = []
mutex = []
process = []
for i in range(n):
        m.append(mmap(-1, 5))
        mutex.append(Lock())
        process.append(Process(target = sub_process, args = (m[i], mutex[i])))
        process[i].start()

for it in range(100):
        total_start_time = time.time_ns() / (10 ** 6)           # milliseconds time
        mmap_dict = {}
        for i in range(n):
                mmap_dict[m[i]] = mutex[i]
        for mmap,mu in mmap_dict.items():
                mu.acquire()
                mmap.seek(0)
                mmap.write(bytes("Hello", "utf-8"))
                mu.release()
        condition = True
        mmap_start_time = time.time_ns() / (10 ** 6)
        while condition:
                l = []                                          # list to hold the mmap that were updated
                for mmap,mu in mmap_dict.items():
                        mu.acquire()
                        mmap.seek(0)
                        if mmap[0] == 99:                       # equivalent to c
                                l.append(mmap)
                        mu.release()
                for mmap in l:del mmap_dict[mmap]
                if len(mmap_dict) == 0:
                        del mmap_dict
                        condition = False
        mmap_end_time = time.time_ns() / (10 ** 6)
        total_end_time = time.time_ns() / (10 ** 6)
        f.write(str(mmap_end_time - mmap_start_time) + "," + str(total_end_time - total_start_time) + "\n")
f.close()
for i in range(n):
        process[i].terminate()
        m[i].close()
```

In each sub process, when it detects that its memory map is updated. The sub process sleeps for 1 millisecond and then updates the memory map.

The outputs were as follows (all the timing are average times of 100 iterations and are in millisecond)

```
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|    Num_Subprocess   |    mmap_time    |    total_time   |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|          1          |   1.122416992   |    1.126069336  |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         10          |   1.115305176   |    1.130327148  |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         40          |   1.133754883   |    1.212219238  |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         80          |   1.172145996   |    1.350251465  |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

I understand that mmap time is in 1.1 range because I'm recording only the time taken for the main process to see the reflection. But, for 40 sub process I expect a total time of at least 2 milliseconds as I sleep for 1 millisecond in the sub process and I only have 36 cores and for 80 sub process, I expect at least 3 milliseconds. Can someone explain why the total time is below the expected value? Is there a bug in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's going on here is that, when the sub process starts to sleep, it doesn't occupy the resources. Instead, another sub process starts to run on the core. I suspect that was the reason, the total time was below the expected values.

Instead of sleep, I tried adding some random computation in the sub workers that takes approximately 1 milliseconds. I bench marked the calculations on my machine.

```
def sub_process(m, mutex):
        while True:
                mutex.acquire()
                if m[0] == 72:
                        for i in range(1000):
                                result = math.pow(math.sqrt(math.cos(math.sin(i*math.pi))),2)
                        m.seek(0)
                        m.write(bytes("child", "utf-8"))
                mutex.release()
                time.sleep(0.00001)
```

Now my results were

```
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|    Num_Subprocess   |    mmap_time    |    total_time   |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|          1          |     1.00910     |     1.01289     |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         10          |     6.29030     |     6.30628     |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         40          |     19.72357    |     19.78807    |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         80          |     51.22329    |     51.33896    |
|---------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Even though, the timing seems to be high now. The results were much more realistic and acceptable.